# How to setup jwplayer with web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwplayer

I'm working on a project where the back end is composed of a AspNet Web Api application. I have a link to download the video archive, but I don't know how to integrate this with the setup of jwplayer. It doesn't work if I just write this link to the File parameter like:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    //file: "big_buck_bunny.mp4",
    file: "http://localhost:52272/api/donwloadfile/1",
    primary: 'flash',
});
```

If I have a local file like in the commented line, it works fine, but not with the link.
This is my back end code:

```
result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = midia.Titulo;
```

Comment: This is a intranet site, you can't accesses. When I access the url "http://localhost:52272/api/donwloadfile/1" on my browser, the download start immediately.

Comment: Oh, i got it now, answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, and it will work:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    //file: "big_buck_bunny.mp4",
    file: "http://localhost:52272/api/donwloadfile/1",
    primary: 'flash',
    type: 'mp4'
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thks